# Accidentally dropped file in WPSystem folder on Windows 10 and it stucked

Tags: windows-10, security

I accidentally dropped a file at D:\WpSystem at my Windows 10 and now I can't take it out of there. Tried to copy, move, binary reading and no success. Any interaction attempt gets the message: "The security ID structure is invalid".

At file properties the security tab only shows the saying: "The requested security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed".

How can I recover my file?

Comment: `WpSystem` isn't a default folder. It was created by a user on the machine and likely used by an application installed by a user on the machine.  I suggest taking ownership of the folder and simply moving the file.

Comment: @Ramhound this folder was created by Age Of Empires HD. When I set new permissions only my dropped file gets the security ID structure message.

Comment: "gets the security ID structure message" - I am not familiar with this message.  Taking ownership of just the file wasn't my suggestion.  Have you taken ownership of the folder, and all the files contained within it, in order to move the file.

Comment: @Ramhound yea, I did. Same error message on that file.

Comment: The only information indicated in your question indicates a permission issue.  If the file is owned by you, then you wouldn't be getting the message, you have received.  You should update your question with all relevant information to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't mentioned any permission denial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79422/discussion-between-ramhound-and-mfedatto).